# How to use object of two class in each other in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes:

- ServiceProviderCompleteProfile
- RadioButton.

By importing the `RadioButton` class in `ServiceProviderCompleteProfile` I can create radio button.

I have declared all method related to radio button in it's own class.

Now I want to enable a textbox in my `ServiceProviderCompleteProfile` instance when a `RadioButton` is selected. To achieve this, I am importing `ServiceProviderCompleteProfile` in `RadioButton` too.

I have written the code below but `ServiceProviderCompleteProfile`s object is not responding.

**Button Initialisation**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andOptions:(NSArray *)options andColumns:(int)columns
{
    self.radioButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        // Initialization code
        int framex = 0;
        framex = frame.size.width / columns;
        int framey = 0;
        framey = frame.size.height / ([options count] / (columns));
        int k = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < ([options count] / columns); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < columns; j++)
            {
                int x = framex*0.20;
                int y = framey*0.20;
                UIButton *btTemp = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(framex*j+x, framey*i+y, framex/2+x, framey/2+y)];
                [btTemp addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                btTemp.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
                [btTemp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [btTemp setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                btTemp.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.f];
                btTemp.titleLabel.numberOfLines=1;
                btTemp.titleLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                btTemp.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                [btTemp setTitle:[options objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                btTemp.tag=j+1;
                [self.radioButtons addObject:btTemp];
                [self addSubview:btTemp];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Button Action**

```
-(IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender
{
    for(int i = 0; i < [self.radioButtons count]; i++)
    {
        [[self.radioButtons objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    genderButtonIndex=[sender tag];

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ServiceProviderProfileViewController *svc=[[ServiceProviderProfileViewController alloc]init];

    if([sender tag] == 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",genderButtonIndex);
        svc.txtGratuity.text=@"h";
        svc.txtGratuity.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        svc.txtGratuity.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use protocol or notifications

Comment: can you please put code snippet?

Comment: @mobiSpace check it please.

Comment: @wuiii how to use protocol for IBAction method...

Comment: Your questions will be much easier to understand if you format them properly. Have a close look at the edit I make and try and keep your questions well formatted in future please.

Comment: @JamesWebster sorry james i tried really hard to put it in well format but i am new to stackoverflow so...and i have no time i have to do this in one hour thats why i post it as it is...newt time i will try to put it in well format....but can u please help me now....

Comment: I realised you were new to SO, that's why I helped with the formatting. I'll read your question properly and attempt an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal pattern is to use a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) and the [delegate pattern](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns).

In your RadioButton header, add a protocol and a delegate implementing that protocol:

```
@protocol RadioButtonDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void) buttonWasActivated:(int) buttonTag;

@end

...

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<RadioButtonDelegate> delegate; //Delegates should always be assign
```

In the implementation, you should add a callback to the IBAction

```
-(IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender
{
    ...
    [_delegate buttonWasActivated:sender.tag];
    ...
}
```

And in your ServiceProviderProfileViewController, set the delegate on the radio button view

```
//Header
@interface ServiceProviderProfileViewController : UIViewController <RadioButtonDelegate>

//Wherever you init radioButtonView
radioButtonView.delegate = self;

//Add a method to implement the protocol
-(void) buttonWasActivated:(int) buttonTag
{
    if (buttonTag == 3) //enable text box
}
```

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) id<RadioButtonDelegate> delegate; line i have to write in @interface???

Comment: james my app. is also crashing at one point...and i think you can fix it....can you help me?

Comment: You should post another question. You should have the crash log, where you think it is breaking and what you've already tried to fix it.

Comment: ok i will notify here you when i post that que. and i have screenshot of that log...

Comment: james can u please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113755/application-is-crashing-while-poping-view-controller

Comment: james can u pls take a look at this...you taught me but still i am getting error... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121615/error-not-found-declaration

Comment: james can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242854/how-to-use-protocol