# Application is crashing while poping view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, ios7, xcode5

Your images have probably been run through Apple's "pngcrush" program and therefore are not valid PNG files any more. I'm told that Apple's "pngcrush" has a way of reverting the damage and recreating a valid PNG from the crushed file, perhaps with some loss of data. If you can look at the beginning of the file and the bytes "CgBI" appear starting at byte 12 instead of "IHDR", that will confirm that the file has indeed been apple-pngcrushed.

Comment: your screenshot is not clear..Paste crash log here @vivek

Comment: Add exception breakpoint and look who is call method `setRememberUserAfterLibraryDismissal:`

Comment: Also there are no sense from your screenshot because it show the `main` function that caught your exception.

Comment: A UINavigationController doesn't have a setRememberUserAfterLibraryDismissal: method. What controller did you intend to send that message to?

Comment: use a try catch block if you need short cut stop here only else log the exception ...it says your method is not defined.

Comment: actually i have present a viewcontroller which has navigation controller. now by clicking on continue button i am pushing paypal sdk pages...and at the time of returning from that sdk pages i am poping to my application viewcontroller.

Comment: If you have presented a viewController then you should dismiss that controller not popViewController.

Comment: @MayurShrivas but after presenting viewcontroller i am pushing paypal pages. and then returning to that presentedviewcontroller by poping.

Comment: Do you set any sort of delegate on paypal? Anything that looks like `paypalHandler.delegate = self` Can we see that. If not, can we see where you create the paypal code please?

Comment: @JamesWebster i have post my code. and also take look at screen shot that i have post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115427/overlapping-of-navigationbar-back-button

Comment: @vivek, can you also show us your code for the required PayPalPaymentDelegate method payPalPaymentViewController:didCompletePayment: ?

Comment: @DaveGoldman i have post delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Ah!

@vivek, instead of this line:

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:paymentViewController.visibleViewController animated:NO];

try this one (as per our [sample code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#sample-code)):

> [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

And also, instead of this one:

> [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES ];

use this:

> [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: yes but as i have mentioned in this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115427/overlapping-of-navigationbar-back-button) question...overlap occured

Comment: @vivek, I'll continue to work with you on your button overlap issue, over in that StackOverflow question. But please do use presentViewController:animated:completion:, as indicated above, to launch the PayPal iOS SDK.