# Overlapping of navigationbar back button

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, ios7, xcode5

I am stuck in navigationcontroller.
Here are screenshots.
1)from this page i am initializing paypal sdk. I am presenting paypal sdk pages.
[image]

2) this page is presenting only for first time.
[image]

3) and then this page is navigating automatically..now when i clikc on cancel it will dismissed. and next time when i will click on continue from first page directly this page will present with perfect UI.

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

@vivek, if you have not already done so, please download the [latest version of the PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) and let us know whether that solves your problem.

Comment: ok i will try this...and one thing i want to tell you that when i have run github demo project...and when paypal sdk call...it will directly call window displaying 3rd snapshot...but when i used it in my project 2nd window always appear in between.

Comment: @vivek, in your project did you also have the environment set to PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork? If instead you were using PayPalEnvironmentSandbox or PayPalEnvironmentProduction, I would indeed expect the 2nd window to be visible for a moment or two.

Comment: and...that screen "checking device" is came for a moment...when app ran for first time...and then from second time directly third window appear without any issues.

Comment: And flow of transition is:First "checking device" window present with navigation bar having cancel button. Then automatically paypal login window navigate(from left side) with navigation bar and having back button...at that time this issue occur..that cancel button of previous checking screen is still there

Comment: Okay. I'll perform some more experiments here and see if I can get the overlap to happen for me, so that I can discover the problem.

Comment: @vivek The problem you're seeing is one that we thought we had fixed in our 1.3.4 release in October. (See https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/46) Are you sure that you are using the latest release of our SDK? If so, then we may need to reopen that github issue.

Comment: In any case, see if the following eliminates the problem for you: Follow our "optional" step 6 at [ https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#sample-code ]. By calling prepareForPaymentUsingClientId: when you first display your own view controller, you will usually circumvent the appearance of the problematic "Checking this device..." screen.

Comment: ok Dave...I really appreciate your help....and yes you are write I have used 1.3.3...i will try latest version 1.4.2 which is also supported 6d bit ios. Hope it will resolve my problem...and another thing that I got from your second comment that...I should not use prepareForPaymentUsingClientId right???

Comment: and another thing I  want to ask you that I need auto recharge functionality in my app...like for first time when client enter his username and password of paypal and make payment...and also there is one filed which ask user if he/she want auto recharge from next time. So is this possible to achieve this ??? Can I able to store user paypal userId in server and from next time according requirement app will deduct predefine amount from user paypal account automatically and recharge client app account.???

Comment: @vivek, you **should** use prepareForPaymentUsingClientId:

Comment: Regarding what you're calling "auto recharge", this feature is not currently included in the SDK. However, it is something that will be coming in the future. (I don't have a specific date estimate for you.)

Comment: overlaping issue solved....i tried new version first but though it was same...then I tried prepareForPaymentUsingClientId: with this method and middle screen disappeared.

Comment: hello dave...I have chaged my library and used 1.4.2 which is supported to 64 bit...but still it is giving me error :
ignoring file /Users/cloudzoninfosoft/Desktop/GratZeez/GratZeez/Applications/PayPal/libPayPalMobile.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/cloudzoninfosoft/Desktop/GratZeez/GratZeez/Applications/PayPal/libPayPalMobile.a

Comment: Hmm. Make sure that you have the correct version of the file at that location. If you check its size, it should be exactly 29,212,964 bytes. If so, then if you launch Terminal and change to that directory, the command `lipo -info libPayPalMobile.a` should display `x86_64` as one of the included architectures.

Comment: I got this result...
lipo -info libPayPalMobile.a
Architectures in the fat file: libPayPalMobile.a are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) i386 x86_64 (cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0))

Comment: @vivek that does indeed seem to be the latest version of our SDK. And it does include the x86_64 architecture, according to `lipo`. I think that if you need to me to help you further with integrating our SDK, you'll need to email me your entire project so that I can try building it here for myself. You can find my email address in my Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: dave can you give me your email id...i will send you my project files

Comment: sorry Dave...I didnt find any Id of you in your profile...may be it is not visible to me...can you give me?

Comment: You didn't see this? "You can reach me at dgoldman, with the ebay domain."

Comment: In my app I want functionality like this: User can make payment via paypal...i have done this...Now I want to do revert of this that....user can make request to receive their money to administrator. And then admin can transfer money to users paypal account...What should I use for that? paypal mass payment???

Comment: @vivek I can only respond about the PayPal iOS SDK itself. For your latest question, please contact [PayPal Developer Tech Support](https://paypal.com/dts).

Comment: Can you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574428/paypal-credit-card-transaction-not-working-in-sandbox-mode