# Upload Image with dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I want to upload image to server from iphone. Using `ASIHttpRequest` and `ASIFormDataRequest` i have sucessfully uplaoded picture to server by

```
[request setdata:...]
```

But I also want to send userId to server with image. How to achieve this? Here is my code...

```
  ASIFormDataRequest *_request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLSaveImage]];
 __unsafe_unretained ASIFormDataRequest *request = _request;
 [ASIHTTPRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES];
 [request setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
 NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(proImage.image,1.0);
 [request setData:data
    withFileName:@"profile.jpg"
  andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
          forKey:@"file"];
```

Comment: use dictionary key-value pair, add one more key with userId.

Comment: what is your request method?

Comment: here is my code can you tell me how to use dictionary with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **POST** method, use **setPostValue: forKey:** with the **setdata:**. You dont need to do any additional work . Just post the variable along with image.

```
[request setPostValue:VALUE forKey:KEY];
[request setData:data withFileName:@"profile.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
      forKey:@"file"];
```

Comment: but how to add image and one more  filed in VALUE

Comment: ok so another field i have to set in VALUE with setPostvalue and image to setdata???

Comment: manujmv...i have another problem also can you take a look at that pls.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115427/overlapping-of-navigationbar-back-button