# Paypal credit card transaction not working in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using paypal ios sdk for payment. I tried to pay with credit card in sandbox mode. I am getting **State=pending**.It accepts my creditcard details but When I click on charge credit card It procees for that and then I got response from paypal :

```
{
client =     {
    environment = sandbox;
    "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.3.3";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
};
payment =     {
    amount = "122.00";
    "currency_code" = USD;
    "short_description" = "Paying to MYAPP";
};
"proof_of_payment" =     {
    "rest_api" =         {
        "payment_id" = "PAY-6SB360568W1073911KLY6KAI";
        state = pending;
    };
};
}
```

It was working fine in NoNetwork/mockmode. Paypal login is also working in sandbox mode. Does I am missing some thing with credit card?

Comment: Is the Merchant account set to different currency other than USD?

Comment: no both are set to USD...payment with paypal login works fine for same

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have Payment Review enabled for the receiving account.  To disable this, click the profile link under the account in your sandbox account list and turn off payment review on the settings tab.