# How to use protocol

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, protocols

I have two viewControllers

- ServiceProvider
- WorkLocation

In `ServiceProvider` I have one text field and a pick button.
When user click on pick button it will redirect to `WorkLocation` which has a list of `location`s.
When user select any `location` and then click on pick button from `WorkLocation` it will redirect back to `ServiceProvider` page with `locationName` and `Id`. And in `ServiceProvider` page `locationName` will be displayed in the text field which is already there.

To perform this I am using a protocol.

WorkLocation declaration:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "WorkDetailCell.h"

@protocol WorkLocationDetailViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
    -(void)organizationInfo:(NSString *) organization_id name:(NSString *)name;
@end

@interface WorkLocationDetailsViewController :UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate >
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *workLocationTableView;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *workLocationSearchBar;
    NSMutableArray *workDetailArray,*tempDataArray,*searchArray,*searchResultArray;
    BOOL search;
 }

 @property (nonatomic,retain) id < WorkLocationDetailViewDelegate > delegate;
```

WorkLocation implementation:

```
 -(IBAction)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    if (search==FALSE) {
        NSLog(@"pick%d",[sender tag]);
        NSLog(@"pick from temp");
         NSDictionary *detailList=[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
        [_delegate organizationInfo:detailList[@"organizationId"] name:detailList[@"organizationName"]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"pick from search");
    }

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and in ServiceProvider implementation file:

```
-(void)organizationInfo:(NSString*)organization_id name:(NSString *)name {
    NSString *id=organization_id;
    txtWorkLocation.text=name;
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",organization_id,name);
}
```

Now when I came back from `WorkLocation` page this method is not called.
Declaration of `ServiceProvider`:

```
#import "WorkLocationDetailsViewController.h"

@class RadioButtonView; 
@class WorkLocationDetailsViewController;

@protocol ServiceProviderProfileDelegate <NSObject>
@required
    -(void)setProImages:(UIImage *)img;
@end

@interface ServiceProviderProfileViewController : UIViewController < UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, RadioButtonDelegate, WorkLocationDetailViewDelegate >
{
    NSString *gratuityStr,*paymentStr;
    RadioButtonView *gratuityGroup,*paymentGroup;
    IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;
    NSString *gratuitySelection,*receivePayment;
    WorkLocationDetailsViewController *WorkVC;
}
```

Comment: Have you assign WorkLocationDetailsViewController delegate to ServiceProvider class? WorkVC.delegate = self

Comment: I can't see any place where you've set ServiceProvider as a delegate to WorkLocationDetailsViewController.

Comment: @Mikael and spaleja...suggest me your way to do this. If you understand what I am trying to implement here.

Comment: did you get any error

Comment: in doneButtonClicked: log your delegate: NSLog(@"%@",_delegate);

Comment: @Mikael... I got null in delegate....

Comment: This may be stupid, but - Are you sure that the code inside if (search==FALSE) is executed?

Comment: yes...I am sure...cause I have written NSLog(@"called"); inside it

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `ServiceProvider` as delegate:

```
[WorkVC setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I have done this in my seviceprovider implement viewwillappear file.

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    usernameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"first_name"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"last_name"]];
    WorkVC.delegate=self;
}

Comment: where do you initiate your WorkLocationDetailsViewController? Like: WorkLocationDetailsViewController *WorkVC = [WorkLocationDetailsViewController alloc] init];

Comment: if you understood what i want to do then suggest me your way to do that thing...or i put more light on that

Comment: And if you log the delegate in WorkLocationDetailsViewController, what do you see?

Comment: I want value from worklocation to serviceprovider. and i didnt get you...how to log delegate in worklocation.??

Comment: the answer from @iDev is probably correct. Use property (unsafe_unretained) id < WorkLocationDetailViewDelegate > delegate; or (assign)

Comment: I tried both...nonatomic,weak and nonatomic,assign...but not working

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use prepareForSegue: method to set text field of the destination view controller? This will make the communication between the view controllers in a standard way, and also reduce your coding effort.

Anyways, your code for implementing protocol looks ok. You need to check WorkVC is initiated before its delegate is set.

Comment: yes i have initiated WorkVC before setting its delegate...But when I log _delegate...I got null value...

Comment: Can you give the code where delegate is being set? Probably, that can give more idea about it.